# R Markdown: PDF Document compile error (pdf backend)

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I decided to write my thesis in rmarkdown and have issues in knitting the document to pdf. It is a very large file. The document works with html_output but has issues in compiling using pdf_output. As I save the latex file using keep_tex I can then run it and it safely outputs a pdf_document (with some formatting issues).

```
date: "8/12/2019"
output: 
 pdf_document:
    keep_tex : true
    latex_engine : lualatex
    includes :
      before_body : Title.sty
    fig_width : 6
    fig_height : 4
    fig_caption : TRUE
    citation_package: biblatex
bibliography: Bibliographytxt.bibtex



output file: Test.knit.md

tlmgr search --file --global "/biblatex-dm.cfg"
tlmgr search --file --global "/Test.bbl"
! error:  (file "Test_files/figure-latex/""Decision_Trees-1".png) (pdf backend):

Error: Failed to compile Test.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Test.log for more info.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In readLines(log) : incomplete final line found on 'Test.log'
2: In parse_packages(logfile, quiet = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)) :
  Failed to find a package that contains biblatex-dm.cfg
3: In parse_packages(logfile, quiet = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)) :
  Failed to find a package that contains Test.bbl
Execution halted
```

Does anyone know why R is reading the file like:

```
! error:  (file "Test_files/figure-latex/""Decision_Trees-1".png) (pdf backend):
```

where the file Decision_Trees-1 is being read somehow in double quotation marks!?

Should it not read "Test_files/figure-latex/Decision_Trees-1.png".

In addition, the knitr::include_graphics("Mypdf.pdf") does not seem to work either when I try to load a file, either in pdf or png format.

Please help.

Comment: Please try to reduce your document to a [mre]. After that you can [edit] your question to include the minimal document.

Comment: Once you have the minimal reproducible example, please also include the intermediate .tex file and the .log file from tex. This might be connected with the recent changes in figure name parsing